# How to upload a file in survey or custom list?

Tags: file-upload

I want my users to upload a document.

I know we can use doc library to upload docs. But Is there any way of providing a field to upload a file in SharePoint survey or custom list?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, you can attach file to list item if it's not prohibited by list options. How to perform this is described [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Attach-files-to-list-items-9b906be7-80bc-46d8-a0ab-e092fb19dbcf):

1. If the list is not already open, click its name on the Quick Launch.

If the name of your list does not appear, click View All Site Content, and then click the name of your list.

2. Point to the item, click the arrow that appears, and then click Edit Item.
3. Click Attach File.

NOTE   If you do not see the Attach File option, your list may not support attachments.

4. In the Name box, enter the path to the file you want to attach, or click Browse to locate the file.
5. Click OK.

TIP   After the item is attached, it will appear in the Attachment section of the list item.

6. To attach another file, repeat steps 3 through 5.

Answer (score 0):

There is attachment option in sharepoint list.
Here you can attach a document with the list item.
May be you can use that.

Comment: Ok..I got it now.Thanks for your response.
But is there any way of uploading a file in sharepoint survey or can we create any customized code to add upload button to survey column?

Comment: You can create a customized solution where you can add a html button and on click of it open "upload" form of a document library. But that will be a purely custom solution. Sorry I don't have much idea about survey lists specifically.

Comment: Ok..Can you please provide a sample solution for this?

Comment: I don't have sample code for this. But it is pretty simple. Just add an input button and on click of it open upload form.